# Throwing exceptions in Haskell and -XDeriveDataTypeable

Tags: haskell

Trying to throw an exception in Haskell:

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = ThisException | ThatException deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception MyException

data CellPos = CellPos Int Int deriving (Show, Read)

test :: String -> IO CellPos
test str = do
{
if length str == 0
then
    throw ThisException;
else
    return (CellPos 0 0);
}
```

Compiler says:

```
Can't make a derived instance of `Typeable MyException':
  You need -XDeriveDataTypeable to derive an instance for this class
In the data type declaration for `MyException'
```

How I can fix it?

Could you also write how I can catch such exception when calling test function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to derive the an instance for the Typeable class for your data type (with `deriving (Show, Typeable)`; a Typeable instance is required for exception types), but this isn't possible in standard Haskell; you need a GHC extension to do it.

You could write a Typeable instance manually, but using `DeriveDataTypeable` is actually the recommended way to do this. To enable the extension, you can put:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

at the top of your source file. Passing `-XDeriveDataTypeable` on the command-line also works, but isn't recommended; it's best to document the language extensions you use at the top of the file, and it also simplifies compilation, as you don't have to remember the flags. (It also isolates the extensions to the files that need them.)

Also, you should replace `throw` with `throwIO` in the definition of `test`, as it [guarantees the correct ordering](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#v%3athrowIO) in the IO monad.

You should also add

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
```

above your imports, as the Prelude's `catch` is for an older exception-handling mechanism that would otherwise clash with Control.Exception when you try and catch an exception.

Catching an exception is simple; you just use [`catch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#v%3acatch):

```
example :: IO ()
example = do
  result <- test "hello" `catch` handler
  ...
  where handler ThisException = putStrLn "Oh no!" >> exitFailure
        handler ThatException = putStrLn "Yikes!" >> exitFailure
```

(The `` foo `catch` bar `` syntax is the same as `catch foo bar`; it works for any function.)

Note that your exception handler has to have the same return type as the action you're running; you could `return` an appropriate `CellPos`, make the exception bubble up to the next handler (probably the global exception handler, which just prints the exception and stops the program) by passing it to `throwIO`, or escape from the program in some other way, like [`System.Exit.exitFailure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Exit.html#v%3aexitWith) in this example.

Comment: Thank you man! Could you also write how I can catch such exception when calling test function?

Answer (score 5):

Either pass in `-XDeriveDataTypeable` at the command line, or put the line

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

at the top of the file.  Either of those methods specify the language extension that GHC needs to derive instances of Data and Typeable.  I prefer the second method, because it limits the scope of the extension to the files that need it.