# DeriveDataTypable in multiple files with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

My Haskell project with multiple files complies with GHC and runs well.

But when I moved it to Cabal I ran into problem `Can't make a derived instance of ...: You need DeriveDataTypeable to derive an instance for this class`.

Found a solution to use `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}`. ([From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853896/throwing-exceptions-in-haskell-and-xderivedatatypeable)) It helped with first code file. But the same error happens when cabal proceeds to second file. I used same pragma but it just does not help.

[image]

Comment: Please always post code as code blocks, not as screenshots. — This error is certainly surprising; are you sure you saved the file and tried compiling actually the same version? And, what compiler version are you using?

Comment: @leftaroundabout the point of screenshot was to show line in code and error together. Yep, im sure about code version, saved commited to git and even re-configured cabal

Comment: GHC Version 9.2.7

Comment: Well, we can't reproduce the problem based on screenshots, and then it will hardly be possible to find an answer either. Make a [MCVE], then we can probably help.

Comment: You can remove `Typeable`  from the deriving clause (it's a special class that's always derived implicitly). You still need the extension for `Data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your capture I guess you have this

```hs
module TelegramClient where
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import ...
.
.
.
```

but extensions should be at the top of the file

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module TelegramClient where

import ...
.
.
.
```

I say so because your capture starts at second line, and I don't see any module header, so I guess the module header is on the first line. That's why is important to use code block instead of screenshots by the way

Comment: Eek! Why is it even possible to have `LANGUAGE` pragmas that have no effect and don't, at least, raise a warning about it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout well I guess it is interpreted as a block comment (`{- ... -}`) IMHO, It makes sense that the compiler doesn't look into comments

Comment: Damn, you right, didn't mention that my window is scrolled a bit down

Comment: @lsmor But If I put e.g. `{-# foo #-}` in the middle of my file, I *do* get a warning. So the compiler is already looking into your comments. It really does seem like a bug that language pragmas get ignored with no warning.

Comment: @DanielWagner umm... looks like a bug, indeed. Thinking about it, the compiler must look into `{-# ... #-}` because of in-file pragmas like `INLINE` or `OVERLAPABLE`. I guess it checks wether or not it is a known pragma, but doesn't check if it is in the right place. Who knows